# Is There Any Reason to Start with the Original Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, version-differences, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I really want to play The Binding of Isaac but I'm not sure which version to get, so what I'm asking is this:
Should I just get Rebirth? Is there any reason for me to want to play the original one first?

Comment: @pinckerman gave a great answer, but as of May 2015, the original Binding of Isaac has gotten an Eternal Edition update. Just a word of warning though: the new Eternal mode is INSANELY HARD. If you want to play it, I would recommend playing the normal mode original BoI or the new BoI: Rebirth first to get used to the gameplay before trying out Eternal mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original *Binding of Isaac* has nothing exclusive, so I think you can start with ***Rebirth***, which is a remake of the original one. The plot and the gameplay are pretty much the same.

The newest version has more characters, more items, more achievements and more challenges, and quite everything that was in the older game is present in Rebirth. And soon will be released a DLC with other contents.
Moreover, the new game has better performance and less bugs, so I recommend you play Rebirth.

Of course the original Binding of Isaac is a great game, but has some limitations due to Flash, so the game wasn't released with all the features that McMillen wanted.

Comment: I approve this message. I'd also point out that Rebirth has proper controller support which was quite a hassle in the original game. The only things that didn't make it to Rebirth from the original that I can think of are the flash-y graphics and some room layouts that were deemed "unfair" and so they were dropped.

Comment: @Aubergine There are still "unfair" room layouts, imho.

Comment: lol, "plot"....

Comment: Well, the intro that explains why Isaac is lost in his basement and has to kill mum is a plot. Isn't it?

Comment: The original game  has also some bugs that will never be patched, since the Flash code is now a garbled mess that requires a lot of attempts just to compile. @shanodin actually there's a plot in the background, discovered through the different endings. It's not War and Peace, but still talks about loss, grief, guilt, remorse and other happy thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

I started with Rebirth and I think it's a good way to start. I played the original one after Rebirth and found it less good. Despite all the items Rebirth have, in comparison to the original one. The original one have some bugs. So starting with Rebirth is a good idea.